# Browser not caching generated images

Tags: image, caching, browser

It seems that during some tests, Firefox will not cache images that are dynamically generated (or loaded from the cache serverside).

[image: demonstration1]
[image: demonstration2]

I tried enabling caching using headers:

```
$expires = 60*60*24*14;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
```

But to no avail. I still get a "200 OK" instead of "304 Not Modified".

Seeking an answer using the search on Stackoverflow, i discovered a hint by someone that they would rather relocate the browser to the image directly.

Like:

```
header("Location: /img/generated/whatever.png");
```

I don't like the approach because it causes two requests.

Could anyone help me out and let me know how i could just get the browser to cache these files?

The Request URL is not changing and it does not contain any seeds or timestamps.

Comment: It’s [`max-age`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.9.3) and not `maxage`.

Comment: Thank You for this observation! I changed it, but unfortunately i still get the same results.

Comment: As for the 304-part: Did you implement an appropriate caching mechanism?

Comment: What is in the request? I would expect a 'if-not-modified-since' header. In that case it's up to the server/script to determine that the image has not changed since that time and return a 304 Not Modified instead of returning a 200 OK and the image.

Comment: @Gumbo What kind ofcaching mechanism do you mean? What would i have to implement? Isn't it usually the case that the browser will cache images by itself. In any case i tried to elaborate using the headers as shown above. To Eddy: Not sure, but the pictures are using normally in <img src=""/> so i would expect the browser to make a proper request. Anyway i looked into it and found this in the Request Headers: Cache-Control max-age=0 - could that be the problem?

Comment: @user1018787 You would only get a 304 response if the server implements HTTP caching mechanisms, i. e. the ability to process and validate the [*Cache-Control* request directives](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.9). Web servers like Apache do this for actual files but don’t do it for generated responses. That would be your task.

Comment: @Gumbo I keep wondering how to implement this.

Comment: @user1018787 Did you try this with other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the other way around. If you do not want to relocate your browser. You might rewrite your URL using .htacess or/and mod_rewrite or other webserver dependent modules. As example the following URL:

```
http://sub.domain.com/img/gen/<param>/.../<paramN>/image.png
```

will be forwarded (without client side redirection) to your script having the param values in the URL. This means you will have only one request.

Examples to do something like this can be found here:

- [.htaccess dynamic imageurl rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410957/htaccess-dynamic-imageurl-rewrite)
- [mod_rewrite dynamic image names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574761/mod-rewrite-dynamic-image-names)
- http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2009/05/19/efficient-caching-with-mod-rewrite/

Comment: Thank You for your input. I am not sure whether this is what i am looking for. Basically i just want to tell the browser to cache the output. The question is, why doesn't it do it on its own, if the request url AND the output stay exactly the same on every request?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is last modified header in your reponse header. ex `Last-Modified:Wed, 15 Feb 2012 10:07:48 GMT`. you can solve this by using this line with your headers.

```
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
```

The reason why you should have this because the browser uses last modidfied header to compare if the file is not modified thus no need to re download the file. :